# Matplotlib date time x axes custom date from file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Let me explain!

I'm working with the subplots shown in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOjH4.png) with python and matplotlib. I have my data stored in csv, and the date comes in the format shown in the picture. I want the date shown in the xaxis to be in the format month/day only: from 2022-04-04 11:00 to 04-04.
[Subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOjH4.png)

I've tried this but i can't customize my date:

x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M').date() for d in date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job-

```
from datetime import datetime


x = list()
for d in date:
    dt = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    x.append(dt.strftime("%m-%d"))
```